# How can I print lua Bytecode without it being converted to its readable equivalent?

Tags: lua

How can I print bytecode (for example `\122`, equivalent to lower-case "z") without it converting to its readable equivalent?

Here is my code:

```lua
symbols = {
        forwardslash = "\47",
        backslash = "\92",
        andsymbol = "\38",
        starthing = "\42",
        hashtag = "\35",
        atsymbol = "\64",
        dot = "\46",
        comma = "\44",
        exclamation = "\33",
        questionmark = "\63",
        speechmark = "\34",
        invertedcomma = "\39",
        percent = "\37",
        dash = "\45",
        underscore = "\95",
        bracket1 = "\40",
        bracket2 = "\41",
        squarebracket1 = "\91",
        squarebracket2 = "\93",
        squiglybracket1 = "\123",
        squiglybracket2 = "\125"
};
print(symbols.bracket1)
```

Code image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDRHZ.jpg

Comment: no, i actually realised it is lower-case z

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.byte`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.byte):

```lua
print(string.byte(symbols.bracket1)) -- prints: 40
```

For future reference I encourage you to first take a look at the [String Manipulation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4) and other chapters of [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/). It's a good piece of documentation, really.

Conversion from `"\40"` to `"("` is due to how escape sequences are handled in Lua. Refer to [Lexical Conventions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1) or see batch example below:

```lua
print("(") -- prints: (
print("\40") -- prints: (
print(string.char(40)) -- prints: (

print(40) -- prints: 40
print(string.byte("(")) -- prints: 40
print(string.byte("\40")) -- prints: 40
print(string.format("%d", 40)) -- prints: 40

print("\\40") -- prints: \40
print(string.format("\\%d", 40)) -- prints: \40
print(string.format("\\%d", string.byte("("))) -- prints: \40
print(string.format("\\%d", string.byte("\40"))) -- prints: \40
```

Comment: @BlankDank, and what's the problem with that? That's exactly what it should print in this case as `symbols.bracket1` is `"\40"` which is an escaped `"("` which in turn is decimal `40`. That's how escape sequences work. If you want something else, format it or skip escape sequence entirely.

Comment: @BlankDank, added an example that might make it more understandable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `string.byte()` with `string.format()` for the backslash...

```
for k,v in pairs(symbols)
 do
  print(k..'='..string.format("\"\\%s\"",string.byte(v)))
 end
```

Puts out...

```
hashtag="\35"
squiglybracket2="\125"
speechmark="\34"
forwardslash="\47"
squarebracket2="\93"
andsymbol="\38"
dash="\45"
squiglybracket1="\123"
exclamation="\33"
bracket2="\41"
backslash="\92"
starthing="\42"
dot="\46"
squarebracket1="\91"
atsymbol="\64"
comma="\44"
invertedcomma="\39"
bracket1="\40"
percent="\37"
underscore="\95"
questionmark="\63"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how can I print only one of the bytecodes inside the table without the speech marks at the beginning at end?

Comment: Just  remove both ```\"``` so it looks like ```"\\%s"```

Comment: ...and use a single print without k and v and replace v with i.e. library.symbols.dot

Comment: ```print(string.format("\\%s",string.byte(library.symbols.dot)))```